# Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

When i try to authenticate my app in Google Plus via Web i get an error:

**Error: invalid_request
Invalid parameter value for redirect_uri: Missing authority: MY_APP:/oauth2callback**

I did everything according to the instructions:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started

However, authentication with Google Plus application runs fine. What's the problem?

Comment: Could you post the GPPSignIn code you are using, and the version of the library? If you can, the URL you are taken to in Mobile Safari as well.

Comment: I have the same issue following example on https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/sign-in the only think I am wondering about give my other attempts is that I am not setting redirect_uri on the client side anywhere, but than I do not think I would have to since that is specifed on the the google console configuration. I am trying to authenticate my server not iOS client.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem because I was using an unconventional bundle id

i.e it was not in the format com.company.appname

I found the solution here. 
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=961

you have to 
add signIn.useClientIDForURLScheme = YES;

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
signIn.clientID = kClientId;
signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
signIn.delegate = self;
signIn.useClientIDForURLScheme = YES;
```

and then change your target->info->url types->url schemes 
property to the dot reverse of your client id.

eg

```
client id = 2299995859-8gt63glaqk4o8l3ouge3nf1qb2h1vyg3.apps.googleusercontent.com
url schema = com.googleusercontent.apps.2299995859-8gt63glaqk4o8l3ouge3nf1qb2h1vyg3
```

Comment: in eg of you is help me for check haha.

Answer (score 0):

This may have to do with running in Simulator vs actual Device! Trying to confirm, but this is what it looks like at least right now as I get completely different and much better behavior.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the OP, same behavior on simulator and devices. Curious why the callback URL posted is only using 1 backslash instead of 2.